# Python - Display range of dates by id in seperate rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have some employee data that shows the list of dates for which they have requested leave

```
emp_id,emp_name,from_date,to_date
101,kevin,2018-12-01,2018-12-05
104,scott,2018-12-02,2018-12-02
```

I am trying to have the above format converted such that each date in the above sample is shown as a seperate row as shown below:

```
emp_id,emp_name,date
101,kevin,2018-12-01
101,kevin,2018-12-02
101,kevin,2018-12-03
101,kevin,2018-12-04
101,kevin,2018-12-05
104,scott,2018-12-02
```

Could anyone advice how could I have this done in pandas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution if `emp_id` values are unique - reshape by [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) and [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ffill.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt(['emp_id','emp_name'], value_name='date')
        .set_index('date')
        .drop('variable', axis=1)
        .groupby(['emp_id', 'emp_name'])
        .resample('d')[[]]
        .ffill()
        .reset_index()
       )

print (df1)
   emp_id emp_name       date
0     101    kevin 2018-12-01
1     101    kevin 2018-12-02
2     101    kevin 2018-12-03
3     101    kevin 2018-12-04
4     101    kevin 2018-12-05
5     104    scott 2018-12-02
```

Another solutions - more general, only necessary default `RangeIndex`:

```
#default RangeIndex
#df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = (df.reset_index()
        .melt(['emp_id','emp_name','index'], value_name='date')
        .set_index('date')
        .drop('variable', axis=1)
        .groupby(['index'])
        .resample('d')[['emp_id','emp_name']]
        .ffill()
        .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
        .reset_index()
       )
```

Or use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) by `Series`s created by [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) with [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = (pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,
                           pd.date_range(r.from_date,r.to_date)) 
                  for r in df.itertuples()])
        .reset_index())
df1.columns = ['date','idx']
df1 = df1.set_index('idx').join(df[['emp_id','emp_name']]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)

        date  emp_id emp_name
0 2018-12-01     101    kevin
1 2018-12-02     101    kevin
2 2018-12-03     101    kevin
3 2018-12-04     101    kevin
4 2018-12-05     101    kevin
5 2018-12-02     104    scott
```

Comment: tried the second solution and found "AttributeError: 'Pandas' object has no attribute 'from_date'"..

Comment: @darkhorse - It is column name, what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: @ jezrael, the columns are emp_id,emp_name,from_date,to_date

Comment: @darkhorse - What return `print (tuple(df.itertuples())[0])` ?

Comment: Pandas(Index=0, _1='emp_id1', _2='scott, _3=Timestamp('2018-08-01 00:00:00'), _4=Timestamp('2018-08-01 00:00:00'))

Comment: @darkhorse - So there is no rename columns? Because it should be `Pandas(Index=0, emp_id=101, emp_name='kevin', from_date=Timestamp('2018-12-01 00:00:00'), to_date=Timestamp('2018-12-05 00:00:00'))`

Comment: @darkhorse - Because it seems your columns are `1,2,3,4`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184981/discussion-between-dark-horse-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each row

```
df_dates =  pd.concat([pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range(row.from_date, row.to_date, freq='D'),
                   'Emp_id': row.emp_id,
                   'Emp_Name': row.emp_name}, columns=['Date', 'Emp_id', 'Emp_Name']) 
               for i, row in df.iterrows()], ignore_index=True)

    print(df_dates)
```